# Generic operations on C++ containers

Tags: c++, stl

How to write generic operations on C++ STL containers? For example,  Java has [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface, which every Java containers (except for maps) implements. I can do operations like add, remove, contains, and iterations regardless of whether the actual container is  LinkedList, HashSet, ArrayBlockingQueue, etc. I find it very powerful.
C++ has iterators, but what about operations like add and remove?
vector has push_back, set has insert, queue has push. How to add something to C++ container in a generic way?

Comment: check section 25 of the C++ Standard, it contains 28 pages of various algorithms, which work on various containers.

Answer (score 21):

**Iteration:**

All standard containers have `iterators` which give ordered access to the elements of the containers. These can also be used in generic algorithms which work on any conforming iterator type.

**Insertion:**

All sequences and associative containers can have elements inserted into them by the expression `c.insert(i, x)` -- where `c` is a sequence or associative container, `i` is an iterator into `c` and `x` is a value that you want to add to `c`.

`std::inserter` and friends can be used to add elements to a sequence or associative container in a generic way.

**Removal:**

For any sequence or associative container the following code works:

```
while (true) {
    X::iterator it(std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), elem));
    if (it == c.end()) break;
    c.erase(it);
}
```

Where `X` is the type of the container, `c` is a container object and `elem` is an object with the value that you want to remove from the container.

For sequences there is the erase-remove idiom, which looks like:

```
c.erase(std::remove(c.begin(), c.end(), elem), c.end());
```

For associative containers you can also do:

```
c.erase(k);
```

Where `k` is a key corresponding to the element that you want to erase.

**A nice interface to all of this:**

See [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/index.html).

**Note** -- these are compile time substitutable, whereas the java ones are run time substitutable. To allow run-time substitution it is necessary to use type erasure (that is -- make a templated sub-class that forwards the required interface to the container that it is instantiated with).

Comment: erase-remove only works on _sequences_, not all standard containers.

Comment: But you've written "or associative container" which were precisely the containers that I was thinking of that you can't use erase-remove on.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the header `<algorithm>`. There are plenty of generic algorithms in there for finding, sorting, counting, copying, etc, that work on anything providing iterators with various specified characteristics.

Answer (score 8):

C++ has [`std::inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/inserter/) and friends to add elements to a container in a generic way.  They are in the header file `iterator`.